# passing html values to javascript functions

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a `ng-repeat` in my view and I want to pass the object from my `ng-repeat` to a `javascript` function but when I try to display it on the console it gives me `undefined`.

Here is my html:

```
<!-- Panel -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        {{card}}
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-heading -->
      <div class="panel-body">


        <div id="nvd3-container" class="md-card" style="overflow-x: auto" ng-if="dataloaded0">

          <md-card-content id="nvd3-scrollable-content"  style="width: {{width}}px; height: 350px;">
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
              <md-tab ng-repeat="pu in selectedKpi" label="{{pu.dprdProuNr}}">

                <md-content class="md-padding">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      {{pu.item1}}
                      {{pu.item2}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </md-content>
              </md-tab>
            </md-tabs>
          </md-card-content>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-body -->
      <a href="" ng-click="footerLinkClicked(pu)">
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <span class="pull-left">Trend</span>
          <span
                                        class="pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
          </span>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /.panel -->
```

Here is my js file that returns undefined:

```
angular.module('App')
    .directive('KpiParameter', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/kpi/kpi-parameter/kpi-parameter.html',

            scope: {
                card: '=',
                kpiParamCallback: '&',
                selectedProductionUnit: '<'

            },

            controller: function($scope, $rootScope, KpiChartFactory, $filter) {


                console.log("!???????");
                console.log($scope.selectedProductionUnit);


                $scope.$watch('selectedProductionUnit', function() {
                    console.log($scope.selectedProductionUnit);
                    console.log("Changed");
                    KpiParamUpdated();
                    $scope.kpiParamCallback({
                        selectedProductionUnit: $scope.productionUnitDefault
                    });

                }, true);


                function KpiParamUpdated() {
                    console.log("KPiParamUpdated");
                    console.log($scope.selectedProductionUnit);
                    $scope.dataloaded0 = true;


                    KpiChartFactory.get({ pu: $scope.selectedProductionUnit }, function(data) {
                        $scope.selectedKpi = data;
                        console.log($scope.selectedKpi);


                        $rootScope.$broadcast('kpiParams', $scope.selectedKpi);
                    });

                }


                $scope.footerLinkClicked = function(pu) {

                    console.log("parameters received :");
                    console.log(pu);


                }


            },
            controllerAs: "KpiPCtrl"
        };
    });
```

Do you have any idea why? I need to define it also in my js file?

Comment: Huh? The function call is _outside_ of that ng-repeat. What did you expect?

Comment: ok, but then my html won't look the same if i close the md-tabs after

Comment: yeah, you'll to figure this out (how to solve it in a way that makes sense for _your_ app)

Comment: Which "pu" do you actually EXPECT outside your ng-repeat, in the footer?

Comment: when i am on a tab i want to pass the value pu.dprdProuNr to another function

Comment: you can probably assign $scope.selected = pu , when the user clicks on a tab to switch context and then use it it your footerClicked function.

Comment: @gaurav5430 something like footerLinkClicked(pu){ $scope.selected =pu } ?

Comment: no...how do you switch tabs ?

Comment: i switch tabs when i click them

Comment: But you have multiple "pu's" listed in 1 tab, so which "pu" do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

As found in the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTab) of AngularMaterial, you can only achieve what you want to do by using `md-on-select`

**Attributes**

**Parameter**   **Type**    **Description**

- **label**     string 
  Optional attribute to specify a simple string as the tab label
- **ng-disabled**  boolean  If present and expression evaluates to truthy, disabled tab selection.
- **md-on-deselect**   expression   Expression to be evaluated after the tab has been de-selected.
- **md-on-select** expression   Expression to be evaluated after the tab has been selected.
- **md-active**    boolean  When true, sets the active tab. Note: There can only be one active tab at a time.

**Note:** This event differs slightly from ng-click, in that if a tab is already selected and then clicked, the event will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `footerLinkClicked()` has no way of knowing which `pu` to use unless you tell it which one to use. And since it's outside of your `ng-repeat`, there's no overly easy way to do that.

`md-tabs` has an attribute called `md-selected` that allows you to store the currently selected index in a variable. So assuming that `selectedKpi` is an array (or is array-like), you can do this:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-selected="selectedTab">
```

and this:

```
<a href="" ng-click="footerLinkClicked(selectedKpi[selectedTab])">
```

and you should be all set.